# Spring-compatible mechanism to manage background jobs

Tags: java, spring

I am working on a new functionality for a multi-tenancy web-app, which allows the admin to start a potentially very long running process (ca. 1 - 5 min) by the click of a button in the admin panel.

However it is crucial that such a task can only be executed ONCE at a time for each tenant. Of course we can disable the button after a click, but we cannot prevent the admin (or another admin) from opening another browser tab and clicking the button again.

Is there any existing library which allows us to:

- Uniquely identify a job (e.g. by an id like "tenant_001_activation_task")
- Start the task in the background
- Query if such a task is already running in the background and if so reject any further calls to this function.

I already had a look into quartz and the Spring TaskExecutor. However these two seem to mainly focus on scheduling tasks at a given time (like a cronjob). What I'm looking for is a solution for running and monitoring a background job at any time programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use Quartz, you can simply annotate the relevant job implementation classes with the @[DisallowConcurrentExecution](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.3.0/org/quartz/DisallowConcurrentExecution.html) annotation.

Please note that this annotation is effective on the Quartz job detail level, not on the job implementation class level. Let us say you have a job implementation class com.foo.MyTenantTask and you annotation this class with the @DisallowConcurrentExecution annotation. Then you register 2 jobs that use this job implementation task - tenant_001_task and tenant_002_task.

If you run tenant_001_task and tenant_002_task, they will be allowed to run concurrently because they are different jobs (job details). However, if you attempt to run multiple instances of tenant_001_task concurrently, Quartz will only execute the first instance and the other instances will be queued up and wait for the first instance to finish executing. Then Quartz will pick one queued instance of tenant_001_task and execute it and so on until all queued up instances of tenant_001_task have been executed.

On the other hand, Quartz will not prevent concurrent execution of tenant_001_task and tenant_002_task instances since these represent different jobs (job details).

Quartz provides various (local, JMX, RMI) APIs that allow you to obtain the list of currently executing jobs, list of all registered jobs and their triggers etc. It will certainly allow you to implement the scheduling logic you described.

If you are building an app to manage and monitor your Quartz jobs, triggers etc., I recommend that you take a quick look into our product called [QuartzDesk](https://www.quartzdesk.com). It is a management and monitoring GUI for all types of Java Quartz-based applications. There is a [public online demo](https://www.quartzdesk.com/try-purchase/request-online-demo-access) and if you want to experiment locally, you can [request a 30-day trial license key](https://www.quartzdesk.com/try-purchase/get-trial-license-key). If you need to interact with your Quartz schedulers programmatically (and possibly remotely), you can use various JAX-WS service APIs provided by QuartzDesk.